# Can I label my Figures as Figure 1.0, Fig 1.5, Fig 2.0, fig 2.5, .. ( in article format)

Tags: floats, numbering

I'm typing up Topological Graph Theory pictures, and I have two pics that correspond to each graph (13 graphs). I would like to be able to reference my figures as in the title, but idk how to set a counter to do that.

```
\begin{document}


\section{Figures for Proposition 1}


\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth, height=0.2\textheight]{../GeoGebra/ItiiP3L/D1}
\caption{\Dons has a unique embedding into \Sph, up to equivalence, by the symmetry of $K_{3,1,1}$.}
\label{fig:D1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth, height=0.2\textheight]{../GeoGebra/ItiiP3L/D1minors}
\caption{\Dons has only two equivalence classes of edges; those that are incident to a vertex of degree 2, and those that are not.}
\label{fig:D1minors}
\end{figure}






\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth, height=0.2\textheight]{../GeoGebra/ItiiP3L/D2}
\caption{\Dtws has four distinct embeddings into \Sph, up to equivalence.}
\label{fig:D2}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth, height=0.2\textheight]{../GeoGebra/ItiiP3L/D2minors}
\caption{\Dtws has only two equivalence classes of edges; those that are contained by $K_4$, and those that are not.}
\label{fig:D2minors}
\end{figure}



\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth, height=0.2\textheight]{../GeoGebra/ItiiP3L/D3}
\caption{\Dths has a unique embedding into \Sph, up to equivalence.}
\label{fig:D3}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth, height=0.2\textheight]{../GeoGebra/ItiiP3L/D3minors}
\caption{\Dths has seven equivalence classes of edges, as highlight in Figure \ref{fig:D3}.}
\label{fig:D3minors}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

When configured, this reads as Figure 1, Figure 2, Figure 3, Figure 4, Figure 5, Figure 6.
However, these six figures refer to only three graphs.  It would be easier for readers of my paper if they were labeled in some way similar to Figure 1.0, Figure 1.5, Figure 2.0, Figure 2.5, Figure 3.0, Figure 3.5, or even Figure 1 A, Figure 1 B, Figure 2 A, Figure 2 B, Figure 3 A, Figure 3 B.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please give us a little sample of your code. We must guess around here. It is not really clear, if you want to change numbers, style, order... You may try `\setcounter{figure}{3}` for the first suggestion in order to increase the figure number to `3`

Comment: You should describe what you mean by 1 and 0 in Fig 1.0. Also, do you mean that the first figure (say) would be Fig 1.0 and the second would be Fig 1.5?

Comment: -Werner;  Yes, I wish for my first Figure to be labeled 1.0, then my second figure to be labeled 1.5, and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may make more sense here to use a 1A, 1B, 2A, 2B, ... numbering, since the 0 and 5 doesn't seem to have any bearing on the contents:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{Figures for Proposition 1}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth, height=0.2\textheight]{example-image-a}
  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}A}
  \caption{Caption one}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth, height=0.2\textheight]{example-image-b}
  \addtocounter{figure}{-1}\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}B}
  \caption{Caption two}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth, height=0.2\textheight]{example-image-c}
  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}A}
  \caption{Caption three}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth, height=0.2\textheight]{example-image-b}
  \addtocounter{figure}{-1}\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}B}
  \caption{Caption four}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth, height=0.2\textheight]{example-image-c}
  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}A}
  \caption{Caption five}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth, height=0.2\textheight]{example-image-a}
  \addtocounter{figure}{-1}\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}B}
  \caption{Caption six}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

For the first-of-two figures, I append `A` to `\thefigure`. For the second-of-two figures, I unstep the `figure` counter (in order to maintain the same number) and append `B` to it.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand\thefigure{%
 \ifodd\value{figure}%
    \the\numexpr(\value{figure}-1)/2\relax.5%
 \else
    \the\numexpr\value{figure}/2\relax.0%
\fi}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}xxx\caption{zzz}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}xxx\caption{zzz}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}xxx\caption{zzz}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}xxx\caption{zzz}\end{figure}

\end{document}
```